# How to reverse boolean in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a data as below.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "exist": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "exist": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "exist": false
  }
]
```

Only one object can have exist true. So when I findOneAndUpdate({_id:2}),{exist:true}), I hope that exist of 'id:1' is changed to false automatically in one query using aggregate or etc.
could you recommend some idea fot it? Thank you so much for reading my question.

Comment: add your query here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can use the aggregation pipeline for updates so you can do something like this:

```
db.your_collection.update(
  {
    $or: [
      {
        id: 2,
        exist: false
      },
      {
        id: {$ne: 2},
        exist: true
      }
    ]
  },
  [{$set: {exist: {$eq: [ "$exist", false ] }}}], 
  {multi: true}
)
```

Explain:

- The filter will find records that has id you want and not exist or don't have the id but exist is true. In this case, it will find:

  ```
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "exist": true
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "exist": false
    }
  ]
  ```
- The update reverse `exist` field of found records.